# How to tell how much memory is left on the SD card?

Tags: sd-card, storage

I have a raspberry pi, I've downloaded quite a few extras on it.

I would like to be able to check how much memory I have left on my SD card. Is there a command that tells you memory available?   Is the info in a file somewhere?  Or do I have to check it with another computer?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`df -h /dev/root`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       2.3G  2.1G   86M  97% /
```

Answer (score 8):

As others have mentioned, **df -h** will give you overview. Also useful:

`du -csh` (show total disk space used in current tree)

`du -csh /path` (show total space used in specified tree)

`du -csh` (show space used in subdirectories)

You can also install the `durep` package which will give you a more granular breakdown of disk usage.

Answer (score 7):

Issuing

```
df -h
```

from SSH or the terminal is by far the easiest way to view disk space on all devices, on any Linux computer.

Answer (score 1):

SUre you can use `df` or `du` but you can also get fancy with `ncdu` ! Very useful.

[image]