# How come my Raspberry Pi doesn't show total storage?

Tags: usb

I have attached and mounted a usb drive to my Raspberry Pi for extra storage. I look in folders to see the total storage of the Pi but it still stays the same. Does it only show the total storage of the micro SD? Or is it supposed to show everything?

Comment: It depends where you're looking. If you're in the SD card then it will show the space there. You need to go to the mounted storage to see it's space. Try `df -h` in the terminal to see the space on all mounted filesystems/storeage devices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell how much memory is left on the SD card?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11845/how-to-tell-how-much-memory-is-left-on-the-sd-card)

Answer (score 0):

As above @mintyfreshpenguin said that to see all storage on your raspberry pi, do  df -h.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.